# Could humans make honey in the same way that bees make honey?

Tags: food

I was thinking of a situation in which humans try to collect a lot of nectar in order to produce honey.  Some of the people then drink the nectar and then regurgitate it back out and then they use fans to try to evaporate the water out of the nectar.  Would this strategy produce honey if humans did it?

Comment: Possible using advanced gene splicing and also perhaps gene therapy to cure any allergic reaction to pollen.

Comment: Eeeewwwwwwwwww.

Comment: I've seen plenty of people drink "nectar" and what came out after wasnt nice ;)

Comment: I don't care if this strategy works, because I am not going to eat that...

Answer (score 9):

No, for two reasons.  First, anything a human drinks and then vomits out comes up mixed with stomach acid and partially digested food, which is not going to make appetizing honey. (Assuming no genetic modifications like a separate nectar storage organ.)  Second, it'd be logistically (& probably energetically) impossible, since making 1 lb (about 0.5 kg) of honey requires the nectar of about 2 million flowers.  A hive will have several tens of thousands of worker bees to produce its honey.  (Both numbers per Google.)